# YouTube videos I downloaded using Video Downloader are missing the video, i.e. only have audio

Tags: video, youtube

I installed Video Downloader from the Ubuntu store recently. The videos I downloaded with this app only have audio and no video when played, using either VLC media player or Videos. Only the YouTube thumbnail image is displayed.

The Ubuntu version I'm currently using is 20.04.1 LTS. My browser is Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Can you try downloading the same video with `youtube-dl`?

Comment: I don't know how to use terminal commands. I couldn't work out how to use that app in terminal so I installed Video Downloader instead. Could you please tell me what commands to enter to download with youtube-dl?

Comment: I have not done this in a while, and as I tested it I found that something has changes related to cookies and age related content and general restrictiveness.  I need to figure out how to do it myself, now.

Comment: Charles Green - I tried youtube-dl (for terminal) and it downloads YT videos for me fine.

Comment: I had meant to look this up today, actually!  I had used the version of youtube-dl which is provided in the repositories (which does not work for me) and have changed to the one that is loaded with python, and found that works.  I would suggest that you type that in as an answer....

Comment: My question is about VideoDownloader, the desktop equivalent of youtube-dl. It's slightly easier to use.